# MS Access Logon Box

Tags: ms-access

I've inherited an MS Access database, uses code to grant permissions. The very first thing that open is a logon box that asks for a User ID, then uses that ID in the Control Panel code. The Control Panel is set as the form that opens with the database, but I can't find what opens the Logon Box. It's not in an autoexec (Checked for hidden ones). The Logon box even opens when you create a blank database.... so any ideas where this thing is hiding> Current version is Access 2013, but was created in 2003

Answer (score 1):

You've probably just encountered user-level security. It's a feature in MS Access that has been deprecated starting with Access 2007, but still hangs around for compatibility reasons.

By the sound of it (it popping up even if you create a new database), your default workgroup file has been altered.

A full explanation of how workgroup files work and how you can change default workgroup files would go to deep for a SO answer, but all the relevant information can be found on [this Office support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-or-change-Access-2003-user-level-security-in-Access-2007-or-higher-0C6A10E7-966F-44F4-864E-5D2EF79439FA?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Note that it refers to Office 2007, but is also valid for higher versions.

For your case, mainly the parts about the system workgroup are relevant.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, the previous person who created it did implement user level security and a password, which was overkill since it resides on a restricted network drive. I've removed the user level security by exporting everything to a new database, but that popup is still there. I'll check the link you gave me. thanks!